# opengl shaders getting started problem

Tags: opengl, shaders, fragment-shader

I'm following [this](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-8-basic-shading/) tutorial for shading in opengl. However I wanted to start with [another shader](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ILIM/projects/LT/scattering_model/scattering_model.html) to make things more interesting

So this gives me the following code:

```
// Include standard headers
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>

// Include GLEW
#include <GL/glew.h>

// Include GLFW
#include <glfw3.h>
GLFWwindow* window;

// Include GLM
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
using namespace glm;

#include <common/shader.hpp>
#include <common/texture.hpp>
#include <common/controls.hpp>
#include <common/objloader.hpp>
#include <common/vboindexer.hpp>

int main( void )
{
    // Initialise GLFW
    if( !glfwInit() )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n" );
        return -1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    // Open a window and create its OpenGL context
    window = glfwCreateWindow( 1024, 768, "Tutorial 08 - Basic Shading", NULL, NULL);
    if( window == NULL ){
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window. If you have an Intel GPU, they are not 3.3 compatible. Try the 2.1 version of the tutorials.\n" );
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // Initialize GLEW
    glewExperimental = true; // Needed for core profile
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Ensure we can capture the escape key being pressed below
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);
    glfwSetCursorPos(window, 1024/2, 768/2);

    // Dark blue background
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);

    // Enable depth test
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    // Accept fragment if it closer to the camera than the former one
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS); 

    // Cull triangles which normal is not towards the camera
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    GLuint VertexArrayID;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
    glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);

    // Create and compile our GLSL program from the shaders
    GLuint programID = LoadShaders( "StandardShading.vertexshader", "StandardShading.fragmentshader" );

    // Get a handle for our "MVP" uniform
    GLuint MatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "MVP");
    GLuint ViewMatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "V");
    GLuint ModelMatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "M");

    // Load the texture
    GLuint Texture = loadDDS("uvmap.DDS");

    // Get a handle for our "myTextureSampler" uniform
    GLuint TextureID  = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "myTextureSampler");

    // Read our .obj file
    std::vector<glm::vec3> vertices;
    std::vector<glm::vec2> uvs;
    std::vector<glm::vec3> normals;
    bool res = loadOBJ("suzanne.obj", vertices, uvs, normals);

    // Load it into a VBO

    GLuint vertexbuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLuint uvbuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &uvbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvs.size() * sizeof(glm::vec2), &uvs[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLuint normalbuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &normalbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normals.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &normals[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Get a handle for our "LightPosition" uniform
    glUseProgram(programID);
    GLuint LightID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "LightPosition_worldspace");

    do{

        // Clear the screen
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Use our shader
        glUseProgram(programID);

        // Compute the MVP matrix from keyboard and mouse input
        computeMatricesFromInputs();
        glm::mat4 ProjectionMatrix = getProjectionMatrix();
        glm::mat4 ViewMatrix = getViewMatrix();
        glm::mat4 ModelMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0);
        glm::mat4 MVP = ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix;

        // Send our transformation to the currently bound shader, 
        // in the "MVP" uniform
        glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(ModelMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &ModelMatrix[0][0]);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(ViewMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &ViewMatrix[0][0]);

        glm::vec3 lightPos = glm::vec3(4,4,4);
        glUniform3f(LightID, lightPos.x, lightPos.y, lightPos.z);

        // Bind our texture in Texture Unit 0
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture);
        // Set our "myTextureSampler" sampler to user Texture Unit 0
        glUniform1i(TextureID, 0);

        // 1rst attribute buffer : vertices
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(
            0,                  // attribute
            3,                  // size
            GL_FLOAT,           // type
            GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
            0,                  // stride
            (void*)0            // array buffer offset
        );

        // 2nd attribute buffer : UVs
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvbuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(
            1,                                // attribute
            2,                                // size
            GL_FLOAT,                         // type
            GL_FALSE,                         // normalized?
            0,                                // stride
            (void*)0                          // array buffer offset
        );

        // 3rd attribute buffer : normals
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalbuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(
            2,                                // attribute
            3,                                // size
            GL_FLOAT,                         // type
            GL_FALSE,                         // normalized?
            0,                                // stride
            (void*)0                          // array buffer offset
        );

        // Draw the triangles !
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.size() );

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);

        // Swap buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();

    } // Check if the ESC key was pressed or the window was closed
    while( glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE ) != GLFW_PRESS &&
           glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0 );

    // Cleanup VBO and shader
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &uvbuffer);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &normalbuffer);
    glDeleteProgram(programID);
    glDeleteTextures(1, &Texture);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);

    // Close OpenGL window and terminate GLFW
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

and the shader

```
/*
 * Bo Sun, Columbia University, All rights reserved
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Permission to use, copy, or modify this software and its documentation
 * for educational and research purposes only and without fee is hereby
 * granted.  
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * 
 * March. 2005
 */

struct frag2app {
  float4 color : COLOR;
};

/*auxiliary functions*/
float A0(float I0, float beta, float Dsv, float gamma)
{
    const float PI = 3.1415926535;
    return (beta*I0*exp(-beta*Dsv*cos(gamma)))/(2*PI*Dsv*sin(gamma));
}
float A1(float beta, float Dsv, float gamma)
{
    return beta*Dsv*sin(gamma);
}

/*functions to compute each radiance component seperately*/
float AirLight(float lightIntensity, 
        float beta, 
        float Dsv, 
        float Dvp, 
        float gammasv,
        samplerRECT F,
        float f_XOffset, 
        float f_XScale, 
        float f_YOffset,        
        float f_YScale)
{
    const float PI = 3.1415926535;
    float u = A1(beta, Dsv, gammasv);
    float v1 = 0.25*PI+0.5*atan((Dvp-Dsv*cos(gammasv))/(Dsv*sin(gammasv)));
    float v2 = 0.5*gammasv;

    float4 f_1=texRECT(F, float2((v1-f_XOffset)*f_XScale, (u-f_YOffset)*f_YScale));
    float4 f_2=texRECT(F, float2((v2-f_XOffset)*f_XScale, (u-f_YOffset)*f_YScale));
    return A0(lightIntensity, beta, Dsv, gammasv)*(f_1.x-f_2.x);
}
float Diffuse(float lightIntensity, 
        float beta, 
        float Kd,
        float Dsp, 
        float Dvp, 
        float thetas,
        samplerRECT G_0,
        float g_0XOffset,
        float g_0XScale, 
        float g_0YOffset,
        float g_0YScale)
{
    const float PI = 3.1415926535;

    float t1 = exp(-beta*Dsp)*max(cos(thetas),0)/Dsp;
    float4 t2 = beta*texRECT(G_0, float2((beta*Dsp-g_0XOffset)*g_0XScale, (thetas-g_0YOffset)*g_0YScale))/(2*PI);
    return (t1+t2.x)*exp(-beta*Dvp)*Kd*lightIntensity/Dsp;
}
float Specular(float lightIntensity, 
        float beta, 
        float Ks,   
        float Dsp, 
        float Dvp,  
        float thetas_,
        samplerRECT G_20,
        float g_20XOffset, 
        float g_20XScale, 
        float g_20YOffset, 
        float g_20YScale)
{
    const float PI=3.1415926535;

    float t1 = exp(-beta*Dsp)*pow(max(cos(thetas_),0),20)/Dsp;
    float4 t2 = beta*texRECT(G_20, float2((beta*Dsp-g_20XOffset)*g_20XScale, (thetas_-g_20YOffset)*g_20YScale))/(2*PI);
    return (t1+t2.x)*exp(-beta*Dvp)*Ks*lightIntensity/Dsp;
}

/*main function*/
frag2app fmain( float4 objPos : TEXCOORD3,
        float3 normal : TEXCOORD4,
        float4 color : COLOR,

        uniform float3 lightPosition,
        uniform float3 viewPosition,
        uniform float lightIntensity,
        uniform float beta,
        uniform float Kd,
        uniform float Ks,

        uniform samplerRECT F,
        uniform float f_XOffset,
        uniform float f_XScale,
        uniform float f_YOffset,
        uniform float f_YScale,

        uniform samplerRECT G_0,
        uniform float g_0XOffset,
        uniform float g_0XScale,
        uniform float g_0YOffset,
        uniform float g_0YScale,

        uniform samplerRECT G_20,
        uniform float g_20XOffset,
        uniform float g_20XScale,
        uniform float g_20YOffset,
        uniform float g_20YScale)
{
    beta=4;
    frag2app OUT;
    const float PI = 3.1415926535;

    /*preparing parameters*/
    float3 N = normalize(normal);
    float3 V = normalize(objPos.xyz-viewPosition);
    float3 S = normalize(lightPosition-viewPosition);
    float3 L = normalize(lightPosition-objPos.xyz);
    float3 RV = reflect(V, N);

    float Dvp = length(viewPosition-objPos.xyz);
    float Dsv = length(lightPosition-viewPosition);
    float Dsp = length(lightPosition-objPos.xyz);
    float gamma = acos(dot(S, V));
    float thetas = acos(dot(N, L));
    float thetas_ = acos(dot(L, RV));

    /*compute airlight, diffuse and specular color seperately using our model in the paper*/
    float airlight = AirLight(lightIntensity, beta, Dsv, Dvp, gamma, F, f_XOffset,f_XScale, f_YOffset,f_YScale);
    float diffuse = Diffuse(lightIntensity, beta, Kd, Dsp, Dvp, thetas, G_0, g_0XOffset,g_0XScale, g_0YOffset,g_0YScale);
    float specular = Specular(lightIntensity, beta, Ks, Dsp, Dvp, thetas_, G_20, g_20XOffset, g_20XScale, g_20YOffset, g_20YScale);

    /*diffuse color-red, airlight color-white, specular color-white*/
    OUT.color = float4(diffuse+airlight+specular,specular+airlight,specular+airlight, 0);
    return OUT;
}
```

However this shader does not compile with the following log:

```
Compiling shader : StandardShading.vertexshader

Compiling shader : StandardShading.fragmentshader
0:14(2): error: syntax error, unexpected NEW_IDENTIFIER

Linking program
error: linking with uncompiled shader
```

And what's also unclear to me is how I can later chance the Beta value used in the shader? Any ideas?

Comment: wrong language of shader, GLSL has `vec4` for it's 4 component float variable,

Comment: So is there an easy way to fix that or does it require complete rewrite and would I be better off using a different tutorial combination?

Comment: @ratchetfreak - the shader is actually and obviously HLSL, not GLSL.